# Strange Access Database Instance: Object Required VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

I have an application with a connection to an access database that I cannot seem to figure out. Its not connected by ODBC. In the code, the database is accessed as below:

```
With datstudent
.DatabaseName = App.Path & "\Student.mdb"
.Recordsource = "Studentinfo"
.Refresh
End With
```

The student database is in the application folder. However, if I change the database name in the code as well as the actual database fie, I get the error: Object required

Comment: Maybe something in this article will help..  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225962

Comment: @Suzy havn't found anything, but thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your original post and include additional info? I think it would be helpful to see more of source code, denoting the line of code that is causing the error.